# Why do you have to add parentheses to + - operations when concatenating?

Tags: php, operator-precedence

I was writing a small program when I encountered something strange.
If I wanted PHP to present an arithmetic operations of addition or subtraction with an echo statement and the outcome of the operation I had to add parentheses or the html page wouldn't present the operation but just the outcome.

Below is a reduced example.

first case (without parentheses):

```
$a = 10;
$b = 5;
echo "$a + $b = ".$a + $b."<br>"; // 15
echo "$a - $b = ".$a - $b."<br>"; // 5
echo "$a * $b = ".$a * $b."<br>"; // 10 * 5 = 50
echo "$a / $b = ".$a / $b."<br>"; // 10 / 5 = 2
echo "$a % $b = ".$a % $b."<br>"; // 10 % 5 = 0
```

second case (with parentheses):

```
$a = 10;
$b = 5;
echo "$a + $b = ".($a + $b)."<br>"; // 10 + 5 = 15
echo "$a - $b = ".($a - $b)."<br>"; // 10 - 5 = 5
echo "$a * $b = ".($a * $b)."<br>"; // 10 * 5 = 50
echo "$a / $b = ".($a / $b)."<br>"; // 10 / 5 = 2
echo "$a % $b = ".($a % $b)."<br>"; // 10 % 5 = 0
```

Could anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: In two words, ["__Operator Precedence__"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry, though the precedence of operators certainly does play a role here it is unclear why the OP gets the describe output. I checked and got the same result. Since you apparently know what is happening, would you mind to elaborate your comment? Thanks!

Comment: A hint specifically regarding the use of `echo`. Don't concatenate! Instead use `,`. E.g. `echo "$a + $b = ", $a + $b, "<br>";` You'll never run into these problems again.

Comment: @arkascha - looks like Pepo_rasta has explained it quite well in their answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) by  Mark Baker you can see that

> Addition, subtraction, and string concatenation have equal precedence!

in `echo "$a + $b = ".$a + $b."<br>"; //15`

> Concatenate the first string literal and the value of `$a`, then implicitly convert that to a number (10) so you can add `$b` to it, then concatenate the final string literal.

when you put it in brackets, the addition is treated as number(15) therefore no mathematical operations with string

Comment: So the answer to the OPs question is: "an implicit type conversion from string to numeric is done prior to evaluating the `+` operator.

Comment: Which is something I still do not understand. How should a type conversion of "10 + 5 = 10" to a numerical work?

Comment: conversion from string to int take first numbers from it and then convert them to int, everything after number is ignored. In this case `10` is recognized as number ` + 5 = 10` is rest of the string and so its throwed away(read http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and if first character is not a number(expect `+` and `-`) zero is returned

Comment: @Pepo_rasta Ah, ok, that was the important information that is missing in this answer. Thanks!